# How to save read only file without read only mode

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro file which is locked by password and read only, now i wanted to create copy of the same file but without password or read only promte.

```
WB.SaveAs FileName:=path & "\" & FileName, Password:="", AccessMode:=xlShared
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened such a file using Numbers then saved with a different name which killed the password...

Whether that still works is a different question.